# Animating a block element to "fade above" another one

Tags: css, animation

I've got some images links that overlap, and on hover I want the one hovered to appear above the rest.

It's easy to just change the z-index on hover and make that one appear above the rest. But I'm looking for some slicker animation here. I don't think there is a way to animate z-index in CSS, but is there some other opacity trick here I'm missing that could make these links look like they are "fading above" the others?

```
<div class="block-links">
  <a href="#" style="background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/400);"></a>
  <a href="#" style="background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/500);"></a>
</div>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/tenold/pen/dXmXyX

**UPDATE**

In case anyone else comes here looking for this answer, this is what I ended up doing, based on Steve R's answer below. I added some javascript to make it a little more scalable.

http://codepen.io/tenold/pen/qNoNkb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use two elements for your first image, one "behind" and one "in front" of the second image. Set the opacity of the "front" image to 0 and animate that property to 1 on hover. See: http://codepen.io/slrubinstein/pen/EyEyya

```
#front {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

#front:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: That is spot on with the effect that I want, but I only added 2 images for example sake, I have 4 images wide, like this: http://codepen.io/tenold/pen/qNoNkb

Comment: Maybe there is a slicker way to do this with :before and :after.

Comment: I'm sure there is a slicker way! this is the long, drawn-out proof of concept way. You could make this work with four images but right you'll probably want to refactor to make it a little more maintainable. An :after pseudo-class with the same background-image property is a good thought. Here is the effect with 4 images: http://codepen.io/slrubinstein/pen/RRrRxj

Answer (score -1):

Use the CSS3 transition property.  Just add the .fade class to any objects you want to fade.

```
.fade {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 10;
}

.fade:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: But then they have a 0.5 opacity by default.

Comment: You could add a little bit of jQuery to quickly toggle the "fade" class to each element on mouse enter any of them.  That way they sit at full opacity, until one element is hovered, and then jQuery adds the .fade class and drops them all to .5 opacity and the one being hovered fades to full.

Comment: This also doesn't work well, because on when you mouse out, the last one still has 0.5 opacity.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this ?

```css
.block-links {
  position: relative;
}

a {
  float:left;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
  z-index: 0;
  
  opacity: 1;
}

a:last-child {
  top:50px;
  left:-50px;
}

a:hover  {
 z-index: 2;
  animation: fade 1.6s ease;
} 
  @keyframes fade {
  33% { opacity: 0 }
  100% { opacity: 1 }
    
}
```

```html
<div class="block-links">
  <a href="#" style="background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/400);"></a>
  <a href="#" style="background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/500);"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite, they need to be fully opaque by default.

Comment: When you hover on one image, you want to appear above the rest with a "fadein" effect, if I understand right ?

Comment: Yes, but they need to be fully opaque by default. Instead of just the z-index changing and "snapping" them in front of another, I'm looking for a smoother transition here. The effect in @Steve R's answer is the exact effect I'm looking for, but I need it to be more scalable.